# code that checks if value entered is a valid 13 digit ISBN. What is wrong with it??? #Interpreter returns list index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, isbn

```
isbn = []
for Count in range(1,14):
    ISBN = int(input("Please enter the next digit of ISBN: "))
    isbn.append(ISBN)

CalculatedDigit = 0
Count = 1
while Count < 14:
    CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit + isbn[Count]
    Count = Count + 1
    CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit + isbn[Count] * 3
    Count = Count + 1

while CalculatedDigit >= 10 :
     CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit - 10

CalculatedDigit = 10 - CalculatedDigit
if CalculatedDigit == 10:
    CalculatedDigit = 0

if CalculatedDigit == isbn[14]:
    print ("Valid ISBN")
else:
    print ("Invalid ISBN")
```

1. Interpreter returns with "traceback (most recent call last):
   File "python", line 9, in 
   IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Python has zero-based indexing, not one based.